# Why does "sub" prefix have two different pronunciations?

Tags: pronunciation, prefixes

The title tells the story! As an English learner I noticed that some words consisting the "sub" are sometimes pronounced slightly different. For example according to the Merriam-Webster (American accent) in these two words "[*subsidy*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/subsidy)" and "[*subsidiary*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/subsidiary)" you can notice the differences, just click on the words! The guy says the "sub" part in the "subsidy" with a long `a` like vowel sound with this phonetic `/sʌb/`, but when it comes with "subsidiary" you can hear it as `ə`, the schwa sound! Why? Is there any rule(s) or something?

Comment: The difference could just be a result of which syllable of the word is stressed.  In 'subsidy', it's the first (SUB-si-dy), while in 'subsidiary' it's the second (sub-SI-di-a-ry).  Unstressed vowels tend to turn into the 'schwa' sound.

Comment: @QuackE.Duck Both words have the schwa sound; American English generally doesn't have a separate /ʌ/ sound. It's just a matter of stress.

Comment: As a native BrE speaker I can hear no difference when I pronounce the two words. I suggest that it may depend on the speaker, their particular accent and possibly the surrounding words.

Comment: Edited on the assumption you meant "prefixes" rather than "pronouns".

Comment: strictly speaking, "sub" is not a prefix in these words. It is just the initial syllable.

Comment: The linked examples both show səb as the pronunciation of the initial syllable. There is no difference, at least in your linked source.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The general rule you're looking for is that the vowels in stressed syllables are pronounced as you'd expect (in this case /ʌ/), and vowels in unstressed syllables are pronounced *reduced*. About 90% of vowels reduce to a schwa when unstressed.